# Is there a way to get a list of every single directory watched by inotify on a system?

Tags: directory, inotify

I'd like to obtain a complete list of **what** a particular program (not mine, installed as a package) is watching, because some notifications it generates make it appear to be looking at things it shouldn't.
I don't know enough of inotify's internals to know if this is possible nor where to start.

Searching has not been fruitful as I only get results about finding *counts* of watches, which I already have [a great script](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers) for, or about how to watch files oneself, which I also know how to do.